# How to explain the code output of this multi-threading program in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying multi-threading in java and wrote the following code.

```
    public class MulThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1; i<5;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }


public static void main(String [] args)
{
    MulThread t1 = new MulThread();
    MulThread t2 = new MulThread();
    MulThread t3 = new MulThread();

    t1.start();
    t1.run();
    t2.start();
    t2.run();

    t3.start();
    t3.run();

}
}
```

I discussed this with some friends, and I came to the conclusion that the output should be a complete mess. But for some reason, the compiler *always* produces the following output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

Can someone explain what exactly is happening here when the threads reach the scheduler? Why isn't the output a mess of 1, 2, 3, and 4, each repeated 6 times in a random soup?

A few of my mentors tell me it's just a coincidence, and it depends on my OS or something, but I'm skeptical about that. I've run the code over 10 times, and it always produces the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `t1.start()`, a secondary thread starts and runs the `run()` method.
When you call `t1.run()`, you are executing the `run()` method on the main thread.

This means that `t2.start();` will only be executed after `t1.run();` finished the loop, and at this point the thread created by `t1.start()` has already finished.

Since the loop of the `run()` method contains a large sleep (half a second), there's a very high probability that the outputs of `t1.start()` (which runs on a secondary thread) and `t1.run()` (which runs on the main thread) will be interleaved (since that sleep is enough time for the second thread to get control and print the next output while the first thread is sleeping).

If you reduce the sleep period, you'll probably see different output.

Comment: oh perfect, thanks eran. I didn't realise that run() would ask the method to run on the main thread and it wouldn't be able to process anything before that finishes!

Comment: just one more final query, if i didn't have the sleep at all, it would STILL print in groups of 2, but in a random fashion like, 1.2.1.4.2.3.4 right?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Actually no, since without the sleep the main thread loops (invoked by the direct calls to `run()`) may finish before the secondary threads are even started, so you'll get 1.2.3.4 followed by a seemingly random order.

Comment: you're correct, the output just for t1.start(); t1.run(); and no other thread object always is 1234-1234

Comment: thinking a little more on your answer, it shouldn't *always* be like that right? After all it's actually 2 threads competing with one another to finish their tasks, and since they both have default priorities the scheduler can select any one without bias. So the output should still remain unpredictable?

Comment: `the main thread loops (invoked by the direct calls to run()) may finish before the secondary threads are even started` doesn't seem correct, since it *is* multithreading

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw When there is no `Thread.sleep()` involved, and the work of the `run()` method is so small, it's not likely the scheduler would start the secondary thread before the main thread finishes running the loop.

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw I meant that `t1.run()` would finish before the thread is started for `t1.start()` and `t2.run()` would finish before the thread is started for `t2.start()`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
t1.start();
```

starts the thread as you would want. The threading mechanism will call `run()` under the covers.

But you then call this:

```
t1.run();
```

which calls the `run()` method *directly* and block your main thread whilst it runs (since you're simply calling a blocking method). You don't need this. Simply `start()` and your new thread will run as you expect (separate to your main thread).

Note that calling `run()` directly in these circumstances is often unusual and an indication of confusion!

It's useful to print the thread name in these circumstances (`via Thread.currentThread().getName()`) to see what's going on (and perhaps *naming* your threads too, via a different `Thread` constructor)

Comment: i mean, obviously not in that order, but i'd expect each of 1,2,3,4 to occur THRICE, not 6 times

Comment: You get each occurring six times because you have six calls to `run` (three happening in threads as a result of calling `start`, and three happening when you directly call `run`).

Comment: You're seeing it 6 times, not 3, since you call run() and start() on each thread (i.e. twice as much).

Comment: alright, so 6 times run is called, even then why does the output occur in groups of two? as in, 11-22-33-44-11-22-33-44 and not random?

Comment: You start a thread. It prints 1 2 3 4 with 500ms between each. While it's doing that, you call `run`, which prints 1 2 3 4 with 500 ms between each. So you see 11 (in the first 500ms), 22, 33, 44. Now you start the second thread and see the same output, and then the third thread. I do think there's a small potential for a couple numbers to get mixed up right as one call to `run` ends if the previously started thread hasn't finished, and you just haven't seen it in practice.

Comment: If you get rid of the `run` calls, you should reliably see 111222333444, because all the threads will print 1 in the first 500ms (and that's plenty of time for them all to finish doing that), and then all the threads will print 2 in the next 500ms, etc.